# Basic Gaussian Process simulation/ white noise - massive problem

Tags: random, simulation

I have a certain problem with *Mathematica* or more precisely, myself handling it. It is correlated with a mathematical problem and its realization/simulation in *Mathematica*.

I want to start with the mathematical part:
I am given a gaussian distributed random variable $\epsilon(t)$ with $E\left[\epsilon(t)\right]=0$ and correlation function $E\left[\epsilon(t)\epsilon(s)\right]=\sigma_{\epsilon}^2\delta(t-s)$, so gaussian white noise.
The thing i want to calculate is $E\left[\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\epsilon(t')\mathrm{d}t'\right)\right]$. We see that the integral of a gaussian-distributed random variable is again gaussian distributed, so from the moment generating function of the gaussian distribution we get:
\begin{equation*}
E\left[\exp\left(k X\right)\right]=G(k)=\exp\left(\mu_X k+\frac{1}{2}k^2\sigma_X^2 \right)
\end{equation*}

With $X=\int_{0}^{t}\epsilon(t')\mathrm{d}t'$ it follows that $\mu_X=E\left[X\right]=0$ and $E\left[X^2\right]=\sigma_{\epsilon}^2t$.

So it follows:
\begin{equation*}
G\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=E\left[\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\epsilon(t')\mathrm{d}t'\right)\right]=\exp\left(\frac{1}{8}\sigma^2_\epsilon t\right)
\end{equation*}

So far so good, this is the thing I want to 'get as a result' theoretically.
Now I wanted to verify it with a little simulation in *Mathematica*.

Here is what I did in *Mathematica* (I tried to add comments in my code, please ask if there are questions/ambiguities)

I really hope you guys can help me, I can't work any further without having solved that certain problem...and I'm getting desperate. I also seems that the result depends on the time-steps I choose... But the plots really don't match.

[image: simulation] (simulated with )

[image: theory] (theoretically)

```
Standarddeviation=5;
(*define standard deviation of the gaussian random variable epsilon *)

DeltaT=0.04; 
(* time steps with which i want to evaluate the integral *)

Repetitions=5000; 
(* in order to get a good average, i take 5000 reps*)

Time = 20; 
(*maximal time *)



AverageExactly[t_] := Exp[1/8*Standarddeviation^2*t];
 (*exact average theoretically*)

(*It follows the loop for the 5000 repetitions *)
For[z = 0, z < Repetitions, z++, 
  GaussianDistribution=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,Standarddeviation], 
   Round[Time/DeltaT + 1]];
(*generate Gaussian numbers, there shall be enough that all 
time is covered*)
 SimulatedValue[t_] := Exp[-1/2*Deltat*Sum[GaussianDistribution[[i]],{i,1,t/Deltat}]]; 
 (* Evaluate the integral in form of a sum*)
 ListSimulatedValues = 
  Table[SimulatedValue[t], {t, 0, Time, DeltaT}]; 
(*make a table out of the simulated values*)
 ListAxis = Table[t, {t, 0, Time, Deltat}]; 
(*define the axis-values*)


 ListSimulatedValuesPlot[z] = 
  Transpose@{# & @@@ ListAxis, # & @@@ 
     ListSimulatedValues}; (*merge both tables*)

 ]

SimulatedAveraged = List[1/Repetitions*Sum[ListSimulatedValuesPlot[z],{z, 0,  Repetitions - 1}]]
 (*average over all 5000 repetitions *)
  ListPlot[SimulatedAveraged =     List[1/Repetitions*Sum[ListSimulatedValuesPlot[z], {z, 0, Repetitions - 1}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0.9, 2}}] (*Plot simulated values *)
Plot[AverageExactly[t], {t, 0, 20}](*Plot theoretical values values *)
```

Comment: "I tried to add comments in my code..." - bless you, dear sir.

Comment: Without having tried the code myself, are you sure the plots are different? Look at the y-axes of both plots; they're completely different so you really can't tell if the lines are the same or not. (Also: if you're expecting exponential behaviour, use `ListLogPlot` to make the plot more readable)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! But yes, sadly I am sure....and can't find the solution anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892930/approximating-the-variance-of-the-integral-of-a-white-noise-gaussian-process) for example. The simulation is band-limited, requiring a correction to the variance of the distribution. If you do that and stick to low values for `time` the agreement is okay.

```
sd = 5;
dt = 0.001;
reps = 10000;
time = 1;

exact[t_] := Exp[1/8*sd^2*t];

gd = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sd/Sqrt[dt]], {Round[time/dt + 1], reps}];

sim = Mean[Exp[-(dt/2) Transpose@Accumulate[gd]]];

Show[
 Plot[exact[t], {t, 0, time}, PlotLegends -> {"Exact"}],
 ListLinePlot[sim, DataRange -> {0, time}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Simulation"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't really understand why you have to scale the standard deviation with $\delta t$ yet, but i hope i will understand it later. The problem is: how would i do this for other processes (not gaussian distributed, but for example the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck-process). I wouldn't  even have any 'theoretical' value to test my simulations

Comment: Another question: for my certain  problem I need the simulation to be accurate for 'longer times'. in fact I have a function that is multiplied with this integral/sum, and I want it to be accurate up to time about 20.

Comment: @Martin I don't fully understand the maths either. The simulation stays accurate up to longer times if you increase the number of reps - so how far you can go will largely depend on how long you are prepared to wait.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help! :)